# Angular Material $mdBottomSheet - split into thumbnail and text horizontally

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-material

I am implementing Angular Material (AM) in Cordova / Phonegap application. I need to use AM Bottom Sheet where its template is adjusted in certain order:
I have one container, split into two parts where:

- Left part is a thumbnail (square) where fits the Bottom Sheet height and thumbnail width is equal to the thumbnail height
- Right part is a text container where fits the Bottom Sheet height and its width takes the remaining from the Bottom Sheet width.

The image below illustrates the Bottom Sheet container split:

[image]

I hope this could be achieved via Angular Material Layout, but no luck so far.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/xRxPox)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="BottomSheetExample" class="md-padding bottomSheetdemoBasicUsage" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-button flex="50" class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showListBottomSheet()">Show bottom sheet</md-button>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="bottom-sheet-template.html">
    <md-bottom-sheet>
      <div style="height:150px" layout="row">
        <div style="background:green; width:150px"></div>
        <div style="background:orange" flex></div>
      </div>
    </md-bottom-sheet>
  </script>
</div>
```

CSS

```
md-bottom-sheet {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])
.controller('BottomSheetExample', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.showListBottomSheet = function() {
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
      templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-template.html',
      controller: 'BottomSheetCtrl'
    });
  };
})

.controller('BottomSheetCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
});
```

Comment: I have to admit your sample works just fine. If I however reduce fixed value from 300px to 150px, the Bottom Sheet doesn't popup completely. Any ideas why is that happened? You can play around with your own sample.

Comment: in fact the issue is with `padding-bottom: 0` and it seems it was already addressed here - https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1211, unfortunately without a clear resolution for Angular Material 1.x. I am not sure I follow you re your question above... This is what I ended up so far - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbWOoG but it would be nice to have this bottom gap removed...

Comment: @AngelTodorov See updated answer. `margin-bottom: -10px;` does the trick :-)

Comment: Thanks, @camden_kid, yes it does!